# Specifying Character Sets With The Curl Command

Tags: shell-script, arch-linux, curl, character-encoding, html

I am attempting to extract a list of Chinese characters from https://lingua.mtsu.edu/chinese-computing/statistics/char/list.php?Which=MO to make a bash script. However, when I ran

```
curl -o list.txt https://lingua.mtsu.edu/chinese-computing/statistics/char/list.php?Which=MO
```

I realised that curl is using UTF-8 encoding instead of the GB2312 encoding which the website uses, changing the Chinese characters into random characters. So my question becomes this: how do I change the encoding that curl uses to download the HTML?

output of

```
curl --version

curl 8.0.1 (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu) libcurl/8.0.1 OpenSSL/3.0.8 zlib/1.2.13 brotli/1.0.9 zstd/1.5.5 libidn2/2.3.4 libpsl/0.21.2 (+libidn2/2.3.4) libssh2/1.10.0 nghttp2/1.52.0
Release-Date: [unreleased]
Protocols: dict file ftp ftps gopher gophers http https imap imaps mqtt pop3 pop3s rtsp scp sftp smb smbs smtp smtps telnet tftp
Features: alt-svc AsynchDNS brotli GSS-API HSTS HTTP2 HTTPS-proxy IDN IPv6 Kerberos Largefile libz NTLM NTLM_WB PSL SPNEGO SSL threadsafe TLS-SRP UnixSockets zstd
```

(I've noticed that this is missing the `CharConv` feature mentioned in the manual page)

Comment: I'm confused: what **exactly** do you think curl is encoding in UTF-8? All that curl does is write what it receives, byte by byte into lists.txt.

Comment: (Had a quick stroll through `curl`'s sourcer code, `CharConv` never did anything you would care about in this context. It used to make a difference on platforms that natively do not support ASCII, specifically OS/400. If you don't work on an IBM mainframe in 1940s-to-1960s-compatibility mode, you don't care. You're using an operating system that knows files, so you're not using OS/400)

Comment: @MarcusMüller The HTML of the website shows Chinese characters, however when I download using curl, the Chinese characters are replaced by random characters, often with each character being replaced by two latin characters with diacritics. This probably implies some type of character encoding issue, especially considering that the website is using the GB2312 character set (which is often used in China), as shown by the "<meta>" tag of the website's HTML, while most other websites use the UTF-8 character set.  1/2

Comment: To show you what I mean, if I were to run the command
`curl -o hanzi.txt 'https://lingua.mtsu.edu/chinese-computing/statistics/char/list.php?Which=MO' && cat hanzi.txt | sed '1,28d' | sed 's/<br>/\n/g' | awk '{print $2}' > list.txt`
This should produce a list of Chinese characters, but instead produces a series of two random (what I am guessing) unicode characters in each line. 2/2

Comment: Another reason I know that this is to do with the character set is because I previously tried making a list of Japanese Chinese characters ("kanji") using https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_j%C5%8Dy%C5%8D_kanji, yet did not encounter any problems (presumably because wikipedia uses the typical UTF-8 character set)

Answer (score 0):

You're mixing things up here.

The file really just contains the bytes exactly as received. `curl` doesn't do any conversion on it. The fact that different **methods of displaying** the file choose different encodings to interpret these bytes has nothing to do with curl!

Your browser, when accessing the site in the first place, probably gets a HTTP header that informs it of the encoding to use. That header is not part of the content, and thus can't be saved to the HTML-containing file.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I found out that I can convert between character sets with `iconv -f GB2312 -t UTF-8 list.txt` and now it works.

Comment: as said, your displaying method expected some character set (UTF-8) and your file was exactly the bytes as received.